# How to use the filters (pipes) in components in Angular 2 (not in DOM using pipes)

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-filters, angular-pipe

In angular 1 we are having **filters**, those filters can be **used in both DOM and Typescript/Javascript**. In **Angular 2** we use **pipes** to do that stuff, but the **pipes are accessible to use only in DOM**. Is there any other way to use the pipe function in Typescipt (components)? Please help if anyone knows about this.

Example:

```
<div *for="let item of items">
    {{item.price | priceFilter }}
</div>
```

I created the user defined pipe called `priceFilter` but i want to do the same filtering in Javascript/Typescript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `pipe` to filter data in component like this:

```
let value = new PriceFilterPipe().transform(this.item.price);
```

I assumed that name of your exported `pipe` class is `PriceFilterPipe`. Of course, you need to import `PriceFilterPipe` in your component as well.